# Iterating through a string and separating input by spaces in C

Tags: c, string, loops, pointers

I have a string such as "first second" and my desired result is for this output:

```
first 
second
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
first
first second
```

I know there is a problem either in my update statements or when I create a substring. If anybody could help me out that would be great. Here is my code down below:

```
int counter = 0; //counter used in loop
int index = test->current_index; //holds the current index of my string, it's initially 0
char *string = test->myString; //holds the whole string

char token_buffer = string[index];

   //before loop: index = 0, counter = 0

   while(test->current_index <= test->end_index) //test->end_index holds last index of string

    {
       while(token_buffer != ' ')
       {
         counter++;
         token_buffer = string[index + counter];

       }    

    char *output_token = malloc(counter+1);


   strncpy( output_token, string, counter );

  //printing token
  printf("%s \n", output_token);


 //update loop (possible problem area!)
  test->current_index += counter;
  index += counter;
  token_buffer+=string[counter];
  counter =0;
  }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess, error would be in `strncpy( output_token, string, counter );
` since `string` will be at the address of first character only. Use `strncpy( output_token, string[index], counter );`

Comment: Also, why are you adding to token_buffer? `token_buffer+=string[counter];`

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of methods for splitting the string into tokens separating them on spaces. The trick is to make it as as efficient and reasonably robust as possible without over-complicating it. The two basic approaches are to either use the (1) "inch-worm" method (simply using 2 pointers, a start and end pointer, to work down the string one-character at a time, or (2) use one of the tokenizing functions provided by libc (e.g. `strtok` or `strsep`).

With the inch-worm method, you have complete control and compete flexibility, but it is up to **you** to keep track of where each pointer is pointing as you work down the string. (a good way to get familiar with this approach is to write the string you are parsing out on **paper** and manually advance the pointers as needed -- coding your routine as your go). An example:

```
char *string = test->myString; //holds the whole string
char *p = string;

while (*p)                      /* while not end of string */
{
    char *sp = p;                  /* set a start pointer */
    while (*p && *p != ' ') p++;   /* advance to space    */
    char *output_token = malloc (p - sp + 1); /* allocate */
    strncpy (output_token, sp, p - sp);         /* copy   */
    output_token[p - sp] = 0;   /* force null-termination */
    printf("   %s\n", output_token); 
    free (output_token);           /* free if not needed  */
    while (*p && *p == ' ') p++;   /* find next non-space */
}
```

The second approach uses `strtok` to do essentially the same thing. **Note:** you are free to place as many characters in the delimiter string as you like and there is no requirement they be the same characters for each call of `strtok`. This can provide a great deal of flexibility. An example:

```
char *string = test->myString; //holds the whole string
char *p = string;   /* pointer to string */
char *tok = NULL;   /* pointer to token  */

for (tok = strtok (p, " "); tok; tok = strtok (NULL, " \n"))
{
    char *output_token = strdup (tok);  /* allocate & copy at once */
    printf("   %s\n", output_token);
    free (output_token);
}
```

If you would like to compare the two with an example, a short example might look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    // char *string = test->myString; //holds the whole string
    char *string = argc > 1 ? argv[1]: "some string with spaces";

    printf ("\n With pointer arithmetic:\n\n");

    char *p = string;
    while (*p)                     /* while not end of string */
    {
        char *sp = p;                  /* set a start pointer */
        while (*p && *p != ' ') p++;    /* advance to space   */
        char *output_token = malloc (p - sp + 1); /* allocate */
        strncpy (output_token, sp, p - sp);         /* copy   */
        output_token[p - sp] = 0;   /* force null-termination */
        printf("   %s\n", output_token); 
        free (output_token);           /* free if not needed  */
        while (*p && *p == ' ') p++;   /* find next non-space */
    }


    printf ("\n With strtok:\n\n");

    p = string;
    char *tok = NULL;      /* pointer to each token in string */

    /* using strtok to separate string into tokens at spaces  */
    for (tok = strtok (p, " "); tok; tok = strtok (NULL, " \n"))
    {
        char *output_token = strdup (tok);
        printf("   %s\n", output_token);
        free (output_token);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example/Output**

```
$ ./bin/charbufsplit "This is a longer string with many more  spaces"

 With pointer arithmetic:

   This
   is
   a
   longer
   string
   with
   many
   more
   spaces

 With strtok:

   This
   is
   a
   longer
   string
   with
   many
   more
   spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the call to `strncpy`.
With:

```
strncpy( output_token, string, counter );
```

You are copying the first `counter` characters from the beginning of `string` of `output_token`. To call `strncpy` you most move the source string to `current_index`. Something like:

```
strncpy( output_token, (char*)(string+test->current_index), counter );
```

at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code:

1. In `strncpy`, everytime while copying to the `output_token`, you are starting to copy from the starting address of `string`.
2. In `while` loop condition `token_buffer != ' '`. Since at the end of string, you don't have a space, so your counter will keep on increasing and go beyond the `test->end_index` until it reads a space.

Correction:

```
counter = 0;
token_buffer = string[counter+index];
while(token_buffer != ' ' && (index+counter)<=test->end_index) //since counter is always set to zero before this loop executes.
{
    counter++;
    token_buffer = string[index+counter];
}

char *output_token = calloc(counter+1);
strncpy(output_token,string+index,counter);
printf("%s \n", output_token);
counter++;    //This is required since when the loop exit, counter would be at the position of ' '.
test->current_index += counter;
index += counter;
```

Add this inside your main while loop.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, it's much appreciated. I replaced my strncpy with: strncpy( output_token, string, counter ), but it seems that a space prints out before every token that's not the first. I cannot locate where this silly error is coming from. I changed my inner while loop condition to:  while((token_buffer != ' ') && (counter<=test->end_index)) and I think that has fixed the second issue you found.

Comment: Wow, this greatly helps in my learning process to see a more streamlined version of my previous code. Thank you again Rakholiya Jenish.

Comment: You may need to heed the warning in the `strncpy` man page. "**Warning:** If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated." (there are a number of ways to handle this, two being (1) manually null-terminate; or (2) use `calloc` instead of `malloc`).

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin, this was something I was not aware of.